# Pyo3: Can you async fill a Python 2D array in Rust?

Tags: rust, pyo3

Is it possible to asynchronously fill (or create) a Python array from Rust? I tried this:

```
// This doesn't work. We pass in a numpy array. In an async function,
// we fill it with 0.0, multiply the number of rows by 5, sleep for 1 second,
#[pyfunction]
fn xsleep2<'a>(py: Python<'a>, val: &'a PyArray2<f32>) -> PyResult<&'a PyAny> {
    let mut val = unsafe { val.as_array_mut() };

    pyo3_asyncio::tokio::future_into_py(py, async move {
        val.fill(0.0);
        let times5 = val.dim().0 * 5;

        sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
        let ret = Python::with_gil(|py| {
            let ret = times5;
            ret.into_py(py)
        });
        Ok(ret)
    })
}
```

The Rust compiler complains: "borrowed data escapes outside of function".

Here is the full error message from `cargo check`:

```
error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of function
  --> src\lib.rs:46:5
   |
43 |   fn xsleep2<'a>(py: Python<'a>, val: &'a PyArray2<f32>) -> PyResult<&'a PyAny> {
   |              --  -- `py` is a reference that is only valid in the function body
   |              |
   |              lifetime `'a` defined here
...
46 | /     pyo3_asyncio::tokio::future_into_py(py, async move {
47 | |         val.fill(0.0);
48 | |         let times5 = val.dim().0 * 5;
49 | |
...  |
55 | |         Ok(ret)
56 | |     })
   | |      ^
   | |      |
   | |______`py` escapes the function body here
   |        argument requires that `'a` must outlive `'static`
   |
   = note: requirement occurs because of the type `ArrayBase<ViewRepr<&mut f32>, Dim<[usize; 2]>>`, which makes the generic argument `ViewRepr<&mut f32>` invariant
   = note: the struct `ArrayBase<S, D>` is invariant over the parameter `S`
   = help: see <https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html> for more information about variance
```

Comment: I've edited the question to add the full error message.

Comment: Why do people use unsafe code when they don't need? Replace `unsafe { val.as_array_mut() }` with `val.readwrite().as_array_mut()`.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like `.readwrite()` was introduced in version 17.1. I've updated all my code and a related 2021 blog [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/nine-rules-for-writing-python-extensions-in-rust-d35ea3a4ec29).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is possible. The problem is that references to Python objects are only valid when the GIL is held, but across await points the GIL may be freed. So your best bet is to only hold [`Py`](https://docs.rs/pyo3/latest/pyo3/prelude/struct.Py.html) objects across await points, and re-acquire the GIL between each await point:

```rust
#[pyfunction]
fn xsleep2<'a>(py: Python<'a>, val: Py<PyArray2<f32>>) -> PyResult<&'a PyAny> {
    pyo3_asyncio::tokio::future_into_py(py, async move {
        let times5 = Python::with_gil(|py| {
            let val = val.as_ref(py);
            let mut val = val.readwrite();
            let mut val = val.as_array_mut();

            val.fill(0.0);
            let times5 = val.dim().0 * 5;
            times5
        });

        sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;

        Ok(times5)
    })
}
```

Comment: I'm hoping to address a user request to support reading genomic data from cloud data (e.g. AWS S3, etc). Each async read, reads a region of data which must be decompressed and then goes into columns of an ndarray.

* Is it easier (possible) to allocated a Python 2-D array on the Rust side and then give ownership to Python? (The final array is very big, so we can't copy the whole.)

* Maybe the Python-to-Rust function should be sync, not async. Then we'd only need to do the async stuff under the covers on the Rust side.